# Reputation changes are not vertically aligned in the "Achievements" dropdown menu

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

Now this is misaligned too!

[image: Screenshot of alignment bug]

Come on, guys… *testing*!

Comment: I recycle a Will classic: *No repro IE6/Vista*

Comment: @rene Hah...... I can't reproduce it in Lynx either tbf

Comment: For me, in Chrome, they are perfectly aligned at 100% zoom. Only zooming breaks the alignment

Comment: Broken for me (to slightly varying degrees) at all zoom levels in Chrome 74 on Win 10 Pro at 200% scaling (which is really 100% scaling lol)

Comment: I'm also on 74 (74.0.3729.157) but Mac. 100% or 150% and it looks fine. Anything else and they start to move around.

Comment: No repro in mac in both chrome and safari. Not even in 400% zoom.

Comment: Not the Will classic I was expecting this time, @rene. I was expecting a cautious inquiry into the baseline anxiety levels of the individual asker upon exposure to [a possible trigger image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg).

Comment: literally suing you for that Cody

Comment: It's fine in Firefox. (66.0.5 (64-bit) on W10.) Even at custom zoom levels.

Comment: Perfectly aligned in chrome and safari in mac. Even when zommed

Comment: Still broken here